# How can I find where the Location of SSL key file is?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I inherited a RedHat server and I'm trying to find the SSL key file that was used to generate the self signed cert so I can make a CSR.

From what poking around I've done, I can't find it in any of the usual locations. Obviously the web browser knows where it is because I get those security warning messages, but how can i find it on the server?

Comment: What web server? Apache and such have particular configuration directives to indicate the private key location. Otherwise, `strace` and log what files the webserver touches when it starts up.

Comment: Maybe share "the usual locations" so we know where you have looked, exactly?

Comment: If you're using a self-signed cert does it really matter if you can't find the original key? Just create a new one; it's all snake oil anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. Upon some more digging, the SSL is managed by the java application that is running on the server.

I first found the key store file

```
find / -name *.p12
```

And then used the key tool to access the certificates

```
{App_Install_Path}/jdk/bin/keytool ....key tool commands....
```

and from there it was a bounce of the application to recognize my certificate changes.

Answer (score 2):

I made this one for Fedora 20. Essentially the same as Red Hat. It's the green part.

[image: /etc/pki structure on Fedora 20]

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using the `find` command? As a user with elevated privileges, so try:

```
find / -type f -name *.key
```

This should - *at the very least* - narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It is under:

/etc/pki

I believe next it's TLS then private.

You'll want to ensure mod SSL is installed and then change your ssl.conf file

Comment: I think it depends where you decided to put it when you run the creation of the certificate command. So, that wouldn't help.